# Is there a way to execute a ULP in eagle with one key stroke?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I need to use the "find.ulp" very, very frequently when triple checking the parts, so this is what I am doing now: click ulp button, enter "fi" to wait for windows to auto finish, then select the auto-tip and then press enter.

I have to check no less than 500 parts, and this is getting kind of counterproductive as well as well, intellectually humiliating.

I mean in Altium Designer all I had to do is to enter the part No. and the view will be teleported and zoomed right to that component.

I must be doing something horribly wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You can define key board shortcuts.

Goto Options -> Assign -> New

You can select any key combination for the Shortcut.(Eg:Ctrl + F). Activating this will invoke the ULP

[image]

My eagle version is 6.2.0